# Understand the $\operatorname{Hom}$ Functor.

Tags: category-theory, intuition

Via Wikipedia I see that $\operatorname{Hom}_C(A,-): C \rightarrow \textbf{Set}$ a covariant functor which maps each object $X$ in $C$ to the set of morphisms $\operatorname{Hom}_C(A,X)$. I am trying to understand this better (the point and applications) as to me as it seems that all one is doing is mapping $X$ to all of the possible morphisms $A \rightrightarrows X$, so $X$ is going to some bundle of morphisms in which it is an element of (it is being mapped to a set of maps that map to itself).

> What new information does this association give?

Digging deeper say we have elements $X,Y$,and $Z \in C$. I can see that we have 3 bundles $\operatorname{Hom}_C(A,X),\operatorname{Hom}_C(A,Y)$, and $\operatorname{Hom}_C(A,Z)$ and that $\operatorname{Hom}_C(A,-)$ is the set of all possible bundles of morphisms from $A$ to any object in $C$, but why have each object i.e. $X,Y,Z$ also map to these bundles?

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: Thanks for the edit Shaun, I will try to remember the different formatting.

Comment: All the important concepts of basic category (i.e. the various incarnations of universal properties), like the Yoneda Lemma, universal arrows, adjoint functors and limits can be naturally expressed in terms of Hom-Functors.

Indeed, the Yoneda lemma states, that considering the functor $\hom(A,-)$ instead of $A$ does not lead to any loss of information. So instead of studying an object $A$ in a very complicated category, one can equally well study the objects $\hom(A,B)$, $B\in C$ in the well-behaved category of Sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Echoing what Jakob said, no 'new' information is gained, but rather it provides us a tool with which we can express that information in an easily manipulable way.

For example, a category theoretic fact that makes it a little more clear why such a form would more easily manipulable: $$\hom(A,\lim F)\cong \lim \hom(A,F(-))$$ and similarly $$\hom(\mathrm{colim} \,F,B)\cong \lim \,\hom(F(-),B)$$ where each of these bijections are natural.  This here makes proving some statements extremely simple (for example, the adjunction of the geometric realization and singular simplicial complex follows rather easily by using these tools).

Additionally, adjunctions show up often in category theory; for example, in Cartesian Closed Categories (CCCs), there is an adjunction between the product and the exponential.  When proving things about objects for which such adjunctions exist, being able to translate into the formulation of these adjunctions gives an indispensable tool.

For example, we will prove that for CCC we have $A^{B\times C}\cong (A^B)^C$ (assuming the Yoneda Lemma, which Jakob mentioned):

\begin{align}
\hom(X,A^{B\times C}) & \cong \hom(X\times (B\times C),A) \\
&\cong \hom(X\times (C\times B),A) \\
& \cong \hom((X\times C)\times B,A) \\
& \cong \hom(X\times C,A^B) \\
& \cong \hom(X,(A^B)^C)
\end{align}
From which by the Yoneda Lemma we conclude that $A^{B\times C}\cong (A^B)^C$.

Similarly, for a CCC with coproducts (I'll denote it by $\oplus$) and products distributing over these, we have $A^{B\oplus C}\cong A^B\times A^C$:

\begin{align}
\hom(X,A^{B\oplus C}) & \cong \hom(X\times (B\oplus C),A) \\
& \cong \hom((X\times B)\oplus (X\times C),A) \\
& \cong \hom(X\times B,A) \times \hom(X\times C,A) \\
& \cong \hom(X,A^B)\times \hom(X,A^C) \\
& \cong \hom(X,A^B\times A^C) 
\end{align}
from which by the Yoneda Lemma we conclude that $A^{B\oplus C}\cong A^B\times A^C$.

(Of course, I made use of other facts in both of these examples; for example the associativity and commutativity of $\times$ in the first and I used the relationships between the $\hom$ functor and limits/colimits in the second.)

Hopefully these examples show you how $\hom$ functors become indispensable when used with the Yoneda Lemma.

Comment: I think you have a typo : isn't it $\hom(\operatorname{colim} F, B) \simeq \operatorname{lim} \hom(F(-),B)$ ? For example, in $\mathsf{Set}$, one has $\hom(A\sqcup C, B) \simeq \hom(A,B) \times \hom(C,B)$.

Comment: Yep, major typo (I used it correctly in the proof of $A^{B\oplus C}\cong A^B\times A^C$ though). Thanks for pointing that out. EDIT: Fixed

Comment: Is there any comprehensive list for Hom-set isomorphisms (such as the couple examples from Hayden), a bit like a trig identity table?

Comment: @Hayden, your answer is extremely helpful. The motivation for the Hom-sets is slightly clearer, but am first trying to understand what these Hom-set functors are (beyond some morphisms from one object to another) - for instance what does mapping $X$ to all of the possible morphisms $A \rightrightarrows X$, (by def: $\operatorname{Hom}(A,X)$) do for me? why map $X$ to some bundle of morphisms in which it is an element of (it is being mapped to a set of maps that map to itself).  Also, what the notation $A^B$ stand for?

Comment: $A^B $ is $\textit {defined}$ as an object satisfying $\hom (X, A^B)\cong\hom (X\times B, A) $, natural in $ X $. Yoneda states, that this indeed defines $ A^B $ up to isomorphism.

Comment: Adding onto what Jakob said, you can think of $A^B$ as an `internal hom object'.  In $\mathbf{Set}$, $A^B$ is the set of all maps from $B$ into $A$, as an example.  The point of $\hom$ in the context of the Yoneda Lemma is not that it captures all maps from some $A$ into $X$, but that it captures all maps from all objects into $X$ (or out of $X$; there is a Yoneda lemma for the contravariant Hom functor and the covariant one), and the Yoneda Lemma says that this can identify $X$ up to isomorphism.  Category Theory itself can largely be considered a theory of abstract functions...

Comment: ...so in a sense it makes perfect sense why we would like everything to be written in terms of $\hom$.  It also captures the fact that in category theory we really don't care about a specific object, but instead allow ourselves to consider the object up to isomorphism.  The point of this is that when you look at an object only up to isomorphism (whatever that means in your category), you get to capture all the essential properties of that object, rather than trivial details. In order to capture this property, we must look at things in terms of morphisms.

Comment: As for what sending $X$ to the hom functor $\hom(-,X)$ (or $\hom(X,-)$, if you want the covariant one) does for you is to put yourself in a situation where the essential properties are the only ones that really matter, and this makes it a natural tool.  The examples I gave in my answer were meant to make concrete the fact that this is a powerful tool...

Comment: ...As an analogy, think of representation theory: studying all of the group representations of a group allows us to easily find normal subgroups, for example, and thus provides an approach to seeing whether a group is simple or not; there are plenty of other facts about the group that you can gather from looking at all of the irreducible representations.  This should give ample motivation as to why we would expect the hom functors to be a tool in showing properties of objects (up to isomorphism).  In the end, working with hom functors is nice because it is a nice environment.

Comment: Note that, in $\mathbf {Set} $, $ A^B $ has a natural construction as the set of functions $ B\longrightarrow A $.